# シェルスクリプトで重複するデータのない配列を作る方法

Tags: bash, shellscript, array

シェルスクリプトで重複するデータのない配列を作りたいのですが、配列に含まれていないデータのみを代入する、もしくは、代入したとしても配列内のデータの重複を取り除く方法を教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

【想定環境】
bash 3.x

Comment: 配列ではなくハッシュテーブル(連想配列)でデータを保持するという方法もあるかと思います。

Comment: ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。折角の良いアイディアですが、今回動作させる環境はbash 3.xしかなく、連想配列は使えないようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

metropolisさんのコメントのように連想配列を使うと、こんな感じでしょうか（bash >= 4.0）。

```
# 重複のある配列
ary=(foo bar foo baz bar)

# aryの各要素を連想配列aaのキーとする
declare -A aa
for x in "${ary[@]}"; do
  aa[$x]=''
done

# aaのキーをaryに入れなおしてできあがり
ary=("${!aa[@]}")

# aryの全要素を出力してみる
echo "${ary[@]}"        #=> bar baz foo
```

**追記：**

連想配列を使わないとなるとこんな感じでしょうか。

```
ary=(foo bar foo baz bar 'a b')

ary2=()
i=0
while read -r x; do
  ary2[i++]="$x"
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]}" | sort -u)
```

Comment: サンプルコードを起こしていただきまして、ありがとうございます。今回動作させる環境はbash 3.xしかなく、連想配列は使えないようです。

Comment: 連想配列を使わない方法を追記しました。

Comment: 追記いただきまして、ありがとうございます。例のaryにあった'a b'は別々のデータになってしまうみたいなので、やはり普通にループで探すしかなさそうですね。

Comment: こちらで試した限りでは、`'a 'b`は1つのデータとして扱かわれる例として示しましたが、別々になりましたか？

Comment: 失礼しました。結果を確認する際にクォーテーションマークが正しく付与されていませんでした。こちらで問題ありません。